# organizing Typescript project output

Tags: typescript

I'm going to try to convince my team to use Typescript for our web app. What is the best practice for organizing the Javascript output files? Omit from source control? And when testing the app, is it better to let the JS output reside in parallel to the TS files, or in some other tree? I happen to use Intellij and it appears to want to keep the Javascript right next to the Typescript.

I'd really like to hear concrete examples for how they organize their TS and JS, and how they test + build their web app using a transpiled approach.

Comment: This is unfortunately the primary forum for Typescript questions, according to TypescriptLang.org, so I am not sure where I should be asking for help if not here...

Comment: @thoughtrepo - No, no it isn't a good fit for Programmers.  It's a) too broad, b) a poll of others' opinions, and c) and invitation to create discussion.  It's a tri-fecta of a bad fit for Programmers.

Comment: @GlenH7 I did say "better suited." Which it is. I agree that it's still too broad and opinionated though.

Comment: @thoughtrepo - the problem with saying "better suited" is that new users don't understand what you really mean.  What you really meant was "Go read their help pages and scope your question down to something reasonable and answerable."  What they heard was "go cross-post this on another site."  The problem should be obvious - they cross-post, see their question closed (again) and deal with more down votes.  Overall, it's a very negative experience for new users.  So please don't suggest other sites unless you're positive the question is a good fit, as written.

Comment: This kind of topic can't be answered in a "help page". I wish there was a more friendly community but I have not found one. Can I instead ask where a better forum would be than this?

Comment: @Eric M The official [TypeScript Gitter Chat](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript) would be a better place for discussion. They really should link to it from the website.

Comment: @thoughtrepo Thanks, that is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best practice for organizing the Javascript output files?

I generally place them next to the `.ts`. It makes it easier to see what is generated and why.

> Omit from source control?

**Definitely**. You don't to review easily *generated* files.

> And when testing the app, is it better to let the JS output reside in parallel to the TS files, or in some other tree

Like I said, next to it. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

To show how this is all opinion, I’ll provide counters to basarat’s answer XD.

> What is the best practice for organizing the Javascript output files?

I always have them generated into another directory. Just like any other compiled language there should be a directory for sources and a directory for the output.

- `src` contains `.ts` files except for definitions. Those go in `typings`.
- `lib` contains server (nodejs) output
- `dist` contains client (browser) outputs

It’s easy to see what’s generated when there’s nothing else in the directory.

As the codebase grows larger it’s also easier to write batch build scripts for separate directories.

> Omit from source control?

It depends. The TypeScript team versions the generated files in the [TSC repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib), but only commits the LKG.

- If you want people to be able to clone the repo and run the code, then version the files.
- If you want people to clone the repo, install dependencies, build, then run the code, then don’t version the files.

If you’re going to be publishing a package to some package manager. There’s usually no need to version generated files.

> And when testing the app, is it better to let the JS output reside in parallel to the TS files, or in some other tree.

Same as above.